# How to Pass Job Parameters to aws-glue-libs Docker Container?

Tags: docker, aws-glue, local

I'm running and developing AWS Glue Job on Docker Container (https://gallery.ecr.aws/glue/aws-glue-libs) and I need to pass Job Parameter so that I can catch it using `getResolvedOptions` as in production. other than that I also need to give `--additional-python-modules` job parameter to install some libraries.

I know I can using pip inside the container, but I want to make it as similar as possible with the production. I also use docker-compose to run the container

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  datacop:
    image: public.ecr.aws/glue/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01
    container_name: aws-glue
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 4040:4040
      - 18080:18080
    environment:
      - AWS_PROFILE=${AWS_PROFILE}
      - DISABLE_SSL=true
    volumes:
      - ~/.aws:/home/glue_user/.aws
      - ./workspace:/home/glue_user/workspace
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use docker-compose, but `docker run`. I'm just adding the params last in the command to spark-submit.

`glue_main.py` is my script I want to execute. Also `--JOB_NAME <some name>` is required, if that is in use inside the script, which it's usually are.

```
/home/glue_user/spark/bin/spark-submit glue_main.py --foo bar --baz 123 --JOB_NAME foo_job
```

This full command for `docker run`:

```
docker run --rm -i \
        -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \
        -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
        -e AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN \
        -e AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION} \
        -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION \
        -p 4040:4040 \
        -e DISABLE_SSL="true" \
            -v $(pwd)/${LOCAL_DEPLOY_DIR}:${REMOTE_DEPLOY_DIR} \
            --workdir="${REMOTE_DEPLOY_DIR}" \
            --entrypoint "/bin/bash" \
            amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01 \
            /home/glue_user/spark/bin/spark-submit ${SCRIPT_NAME} --py-files site-packages.zip ${JOB_ARGS}
```

Using docker-compose is quite the same.
The main glue-script and python-libs are located in local folder `$LOCAL_DEPLOY_DIR` which are mounted to `$REMOTE_DEPLOY_DIR`. The working_dir in the docker-compose app is then set to `$REMOTE_DEPLOY_DIR`

The docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  aws-glue:
    image: public.ecr.aws/glue/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01
    container_name: aws-glue
    tty: true
    working_dir: ${REMOTE_DEPLOY_DIR}
    ports:
      - 4040:4040
      - 18080:18080
    environment:
      - DISABLE_SSL=true
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
      - AWS_REGION=$AWS_REGION
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/${LOCAL_DEPLOY_DIR}:${REMOTE_DEPLOY_DIR}
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

This is the actual command to execute `docker-compose run` with parameters:

```
docker-compose run aws-glue /home/glue_user/spark/bin/spark-submit glue_main.py --foo bar --baz 123 --JOB_NAME foo_job
```

Comment: So in docker compose, we can add it in the command? Lemme try on that

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me.

Comment: I added docker-compose example. If that doesn't help, can you explain what doesn't work?